# Resize IP hit counter with map

Tags: javascript

I am trying to put IP hits and map for my website and have this javascript below which I obtained from https://clustrmaps.com. I have pasted this script below to my index.html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="clustrmaps" src="//cdn.clustrmaps.com/map_v2.js?d=qRfGtCyumKD_k_bVX26frT-dTv89zON7DtvL8oZ95SU&cl=ffffff&w=a"></script>
```

How can I adjust the size of the map shown on my page?

Comment: Look in the browser's Inspector to get the id of the map object (a canvas, perhaps?). Then, `document.getElementById('id_of_your_map_canvas').style.width = x+'px'`, where x is the desired width, in pixels. The same for height. However, if a canvas increases in size, it must be redrawn. You'll have to find a function that does that in the inserted javascript code.

Comment: @Rodrigo So this is what I have from inspect:`<script size="2cm" type="text/javascript" id="clustrmaps" src="//cdn.clustrmaps.com/map_v2.js?d=qRfGtCyumKD_k_bVX26frT-dTv89zON7DtvL8oZ95SU&amp;cl=ffffff&amp;w=a"></script>`. I then put this code as you suggested, but still doesn't change anything. `document.getElementById('clustrmaps').style.width = 50+'px'`

Comment: `clustrmaps` is the id of the script, not of the object where the map is being drawn (which is more probably a `canvas`, inside a `div`, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using an external resource like that, you should consider looking at how the external resource wants to be used.

As an example, at the end of the url in the `script` element there is a bit like `&w=a` that most likely infers that the width should be automatic. If you have an exact size in mind you could change it to be `&w=50`

`<script type="text/javascript" id="clustrmaps" src="//cdn.clustrmaps.com/map_v2.js?cl=ffffff&w=150&t=n&d=qRfGtCyumKD_k_bVX26frT-dTv89zON7DtvL8oZ95SU"></script>`

In this case the `w` parameter is in the middle. `&w=150`